# Clojure Clostache error - No implementation of method: :make-reader of protocol: #'clojure.java.io/IOFactory found for class: nil

Tags: clojure, compojure

Am using clojure - 1.5.1, compojure - 1.1.5, clostache - 1.3.1.

The template file is present under resources/public/templates folder.

Code :

```
(:require [clostache.parser :as cp])

(cp/render-resource "templates/connectionDetails.mustache" {:jmsConnectionName "Michael" :rest-conn-names ["a" "b"]}))
```

The call to Clostache's render-resource is throwing the below Exception :

```
Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :make-reader of protocol: #'clojure.java.io/IOFactory found for class: nil
                  core_deftype.clj:541 clojure.core/-cache-protocol-fn
                             io.clj:73 clojure.java.io/fn[fn]
                            io.clj:106 clojure.java.io/reader
                       RestFn.java:410 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
                          AFn.java:161 clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper
                       RestFn.java:132 clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo
                          core.clj:619 clojure.core/apply
                         core.clj:6278 clojure.core/slurp
                       RestFn.java:410 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
                        parser.clj:396 clostache.parser/render-resource
```

Answer (score 1):

The resource is probably not found because your path seems to be incorrect. `resources` is added to the classpath so to access your template you should use `"public/templates/connectionDetails.mustache"` (it might not make sense to have the templates under `public` if you do not expose them directly from your application).

Comment: Thanks ponzao :) . My bad , yes that was it !

Answer (score 1):

Your templates should be located under the source folder.
In your case that would be:

```
src
|
- templates
  |
  - connectionDetails.mustache
```

The public folder is used for HTML resources pulled from the web application client, i.e CSS, Images, Javascripts etc ...

Clostache is looking at your classpath (i.e src folder) to find the files it needs.